# Duplicate item getting added in list

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to send list of string to web api and this list I am initializing in class constructor and same class I am passing to web api.

When I am initializing the class; list is getting populated properly but after sending it to web api same items are getting added again into the list. Not sure why this happening.

As I am accepting these values from client; If no value are provided by the client then I want to fill the default value into the list.

Below is my code

```
public class RequestDto
    {
        public RequestDto()
        {
            TypeNames = new List<string>();
            TypeNames.Add(new string("Type1"));
            TypeNames.Add(new string("Type2"));
            TypeNames.Add(new string("Type3"));

        }

        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public List<string> TypeNames { get; set; }
    }
```

and then I am passing the class to web api like below

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = "some url";

                var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, objrequestdto);
                postTask.Wait();

                if (postTask.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Do Something
                }
            }
```

and below is my api where after receiving the parameter I can see the items are getting added again.

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetTypeDetails([FromBody] RequestDto requestdto) // Here I am getting duplicate/Repeated Values
        {
            try
            {
                // Some logic

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error("Some Error");
                return StatusCode(500, e.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is how I am populating RequestDto class before calling web api.

**EDIT 1:**

```
RequestDto objrequestdto = GetConfigurations(configName);

private RequestDto GetConfigurations(string configName)
        {

            RequestDto requestdto = new RequestDto();

            /// Add configurations here.

            return requestdto;
        }
```

Because of this I am getting duplicate records in Web API.

Any help on this appreciated!

Comment: this is normal if the object that you send is the same as the object you are sending.

Comment: This is not happening post serialization at the client end point, it has to do with way you are creating  `objrequestdto`, provide that code and also why are you calling Async method in a synchronous manner

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I have edited the question and added the code

Comment: @MrinalKamboj When I making call to the web api it is again calling the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're adding the values in the constructor.

Comment: @Own Pauling Then how should I add the default values in case of no values from the client ?

Comment: I have even tried to set directly to list property instead of constructor, still the duplicate values are getting added

Comment: That shall not be the challenge, since in the constructor OP is also re-initializing `TypeNames = new List<string>();`

Answer (score 1):

You're using default constructor for adding the default values, which is also used by Serializer. Serializer will call your default constructor first, and then it'll populate the items from the JSON.

To prevent duplication, you could use `ISet<>` instead of `List<>`.

```
public class RequestDto
{
    public RequestDto()
    {
        TypeNames = new HashSet<string>();
        TypeNames.Add(new string("Type1"));
        TypeNames.Add(new string("Type2"));
        TypeNames.Add(new string("Type3"));
    }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public ISet<string> TypeNames { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone looking for the answer, I have resolved it by adding below json formatting in Startup.cs file in Web API project.

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
                options.SerializerSettings.ObjectCreationHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;
            });
```

This has resolved the issue for me.